# Migrating MySQL database using Workbench

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

Just a quick question; after reading the online help and workbench documentation it is unclear if when migrating a database from one server to another it will copy or cut the database? I need the database on both servers.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migrating a database means to copy all its data and meta data (provided there are equivalents on MySQL side for source types). There's no problem of course if you migrate MySQL to MySQL.